# Rows automatically expanding in Angular 8 material table with expandable rows when I reroute to the page with the table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a page with a Material table. The table has a custom data source since pagination is server side.  It also has a check box column. The rows in the table are expandable.

**Problem:** The expandable rows work fine until I go to some other page and reroute to the above page again. When I reroute back to the page many rows are in expanded state automatically.

I found one question with a similar issue : [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172189/angular-material-table-with-expandable-rows-automaticly-expanded-when-change-ta?answertab=active#tab-top) However I don't have tabs so the solution mentioned can't be applied to my problem and fundamentally I am not sure why the solution works.

Code snippet which adds the expandable row to the table:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
        <div [@detailExpand]="element === expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
         <div>Expandable row details go here</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
      (click)="toggle(row); expandedElement = expandedElement == row ? null : row"
      [class.element-expanded-row]="expandedElement == element" class="clickable-row element-row">
    </mat-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail'];"
      [@detailExpand]="row === expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

In the TS file I have a variable which I reset to null on ngOnInit:

```
expandedElement: any;
```

Also,
One more behavior that I observed when I come back to the page was that I have to click the row twice to close it which means the condition to collapse and open the row (element === expandedElement) is satisfied just that the row is visible when I come back to the page.

Does any one has any clue what may be the problem?

**Edit :**

The [expandable table example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) on angular materials page doesn't have to use
[@detailExpand] for the expand detail mat-row however I have to use otherwise I see a empty row in between 2 rows of data. Why so? Does it have to do anything with this problem?

```
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail'];"
      [@detailExpand]="row === expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
    </mat-row>
```

Comment: have you tried setting `expandedElement` to `undefined` when the user gets routed to the page?

Comment: I was already setting it to null. Just tried undefined. Doesn't fix the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278357/matsort-breaks-mattable-detail-row-animations) describes the same problem. Basically Sorting breaks animation. In my case as well if I turn off sorting the animation works fine.

Final solution : Use ngClass with CSS animations. Got the solution from the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65198370/1711670.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. 
> Eagerly loaded tabs will initalize the child components but not inject them into the DOM until the tab is activated. 
>
> If the tab contains several complex child components or the tab's contents rely on DOM calculations during initialization, it is advised to lazy load the tab's content.
>
> **(The expandable table is based on DOM calculations)** 
>
> Tab contents can be lazy loaded by declaring the body in a ng-template with the matTabContent attribute.

Search for lazy loading in https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

**EDIT**

I don't know what you are trying to do but the simple expandable table in angular is like this:

```html
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-description">
         here the data you want to display
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky:'true'"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement == element"
      (click)="toggle(row); expandedElement = expandedElement === row ? null : row">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

**DETAIL EXPAND**

This is used for trigger the animation

```html
@Component({
  selector: "table-expandable-rows-example",
  styleUrls: ["table-expandable-rows-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "table-expandable-rows-example.html",
  animations: [
    trigger("detailExpand", [
      state("collapsed", style({ height: "0px", minHeight: "0" })),
      state("expanded", style({ height: "*" })),
      transition(
        "expanded <=> collapsed",
        animate("225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)")
      )
    ])
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks however I still don't get what ng-template and lazy loading has to do with the expandable row. Also I dont have tabs. I just have a table in my view. The table documentation doesnt have anything related to lazy loading.

Comment: Yes I have done the same and its working fine until I go to some other page and come back to the page with the table. When I come back all table rows are expanded. You can see the problem here except that I am not using tabs : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wat7fa-wzk7sh?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html

Comment: In that link the problem is tabs and lazy loading, if you could share the component.ts maybe we would found the error.